# Navbar conditions in blade template user/admin Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Sorry if the question is silly for you but seems like I can't figured t out. I have two functions `isLogged` and `isAdmin`. They work perfectly and based on them I want to create links on my navbar. What I'm trying is this

```
<li>Non Logged users link visible for everyone visiting the site</li>           
    @if(isLoggedIn() && !isAdmin())
        <li>LoggedIn Link</li>

            @if(isLoggedIn() || isAdmin())
                <li><a href="">Both</a></li>
            @endif      

        <li><a href="#">Logged In link</a></li> 
    @elseif(isAdmin())              

        <li><a href="#">Admin Dashboard</a></li>                                        
    @else           
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    @endif
```

Basically what I want to create here is

1. All logged in `users` which aren't `admins` to have some links which aren't visible for admins.
2. All logged in `users` which are `admins` to have different links which are visible only for them.
3. All logged in `users` no matter `admins` or normal users to have addition links to their links.

@if -> (BaseController::isLoggedIn() && !BaseController::isAdmin()) checks if user is logged but not admin

then inside I've placed another if which should show `<li><a href="">Both</a></li>` on `Admins` and users since they are logged in... But I see this link only on logged in `User`. On `Admin` isn't visible.

I'm aware of ACL's but I don't really need acl. I want to accomplish this with conditions like this.

How to construct the conditions?

Comment: the 'Both' link cannot be where you have it. Inside that if block you have already determined the user is not an admin, so you cannot possibly have isAdmin() return true there.

Comment: Yes, but where can be if I want the links which are inside to be visible in both roles?

Comment: just use isLogged() ? doesnt that return true for both? There is even `Auth::check()` that will return true if the user is logged in, im not sure what isLogged() is doing though

Comment: `isLogged()` return true for both.. eg return true if user is logged in or not.. doesn't check if is admin and I still need to check if `isAdmin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your two helper functions work properly, something like this would be cleaner and work better..

```
@if(isLoggedIn())
    // HTML for all logged in users

    @if(isAdmin())
        // HTML for admins only
    @else
        // HTML for non-admins only
    @endif

@endif
```

Comment: Thanks. It's works.. I guess I can arrange it as I want via blade template.

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(isLoggedIn() || isAdmin())
    <li><a href="">Both</a></li>
@endif
```

Put this at the bottom

```
@if(isLoggedIn() && !isAdmin())
```

is preventing it from showing

Edit: try this one

```
@if(isLoggedIn() && !isAdmin())
    <li>LoggedIn Link</li>
@endif
@if(isLoggedIn() || isAdmin())
    <li><a href="">Both</a></li>
@endif      


@if(isAdmin())              

    <li><a href="#">Admin Dashboard</a></li>                                        
@else           
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
@endif
```

Comment: But this way if I put it at the bottom outside the if/elseif/else is showed at the end of the links. I want it to be not at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Saeed answer is a bit cleaner. +1